# KEEP of dplyr left_join not working as expecting?

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

When I do a left_join, I want to keep both join columns . I thought I could do that with KEEP=TRUE . But it doesn't work. Do I misunderstand KEEP?

```r
table_one <- tibble(a = 1:3,
                    b = 1:3)

table_two <- tibble(c = 1:3,
                    d = 1:3)

left_join(table_one, table_two, by = c('a' = 'c'), keep = TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     d
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
```

Where is column c gone?

Comment: From `?left_join` _keep 
If TRUE the by columns are kept in the **nesting joins**._

Comment: Basically `keep` parameter is available only for `nest_join` and not for `left_join`.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks both.